# Spring framework is not returning a JSP file

Tags: xml, spring, jsp, service, controller

I have started the simple spring webpage and have tried to return a jsp page however it returns an error 404 of the jsp not found

**Application properties:**

spring.mvc.view.prefix =/WEB-INF/views/

spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

**Pomp.xml**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Controller**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller

public class LogController {
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(path = "/home")
    public String Hello (){
        return "Main page, under construction";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/login")
    public String Login(){
        return "loginpage";
    }

}
```

**JSP file**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transition//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv = "Content-Type" content = "text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title> Logging Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Loggin page </h1>>
</body>
</html>
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fxZN.png)

i have tried to return a login page from the spring framework however it resulted in the 404 error, not able to find the jsp file

Comment: Your URL is probably wrong.